# Angular microfront end infinite refresh

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to build Angular Micro frontend using webpack module federation. I have added all custom webpack files to the application. All applications builds fine. Also, When I try to access the individual micro frontend from their respective path then it is working fine but when I try to access individual micro frontend from the shell application then it is running into infinite refresh. I am following [this article](https://dev.to/bitovi/how-to-build-a-micro-frontend-with-webpacks-module-federation-plugin-n41) as a reference.

Not sure what else I need to do other than mention here in this article. Any help will appriciated.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution to prevent issues with live reloads. You need to add a publicHost property to your remote's configuration in your angular.json. Hence, adjust the section project/remote-project-name/architect/serve/options as follows:

```
[...] "options": {
+   "publicHost": "http://localhost:3000",
    "port": 3000,
    "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/mfe1/webpack.config.js" } [...]
```

Comment: I didn't need it before but now after migrating to Angular 14 from Angular 12 I was having this issue too, it worked to add the "publicHost".