# App stuck on infinite reload when applying Module Federation Plugin with Angular

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to build Angular Micro frontend using webpack module federation. I have added all custom webpack files to the application. All applications builds fine. Also, When I try to access the individual micro frontend from their respective path then it is working fine but when I try to access individual micro frontend from the shell application then it is running into infinite refresh. I am following [this](https://incora.software/insights/micro-frontend-based-on-angular) article as a reference.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNZYG.gif) behavior can be seen through the attachment when I access the /dashboard route

After a long search, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580827/angular-microfront-end-infinite-refresh) question which is exactly the same problem I'm facing. Although I add the suggestion to add `"publicHost": "http://localhost:3000"` on angular.json, the problem remains the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.